# How do I add Pagination to a table (Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django, bootstrap-4, django-views, pagination

I am trying to **add pagination to one of the tables** for my project, but I can't find any good resources to refer to, all of the docs use some kind of URL query, but I don't want to do that, since it is on the user page.

**Background** --- I am making a mock website for trading for a project and I need the user to be able to see their trade history, and as you can imagine, after any more than 10, the page starts to look very long, so I am trying to find a way to make the table have pages, but I just can't figure it out.

**Aim** -- To add pages to a bootstrap table. The table should be able to go back and forth using buttons.

**My "solution"** - after going through stuff for about an hour, I found [this](https://datatables.net/) but I don't know if it is good/safe.

**Code :**
VIEW -

```
def userPage(request):
    user = request.user
    user_info = user.info
    trades = user_info.trade_set.all().order_by('-time_bought_at') ###I want this queryset to be paginated
    total_trades = trades.count()
    balance = round(user_info.balance)
    
    context = {
        "user" : user,
        "user_info" : user_info,
        "trades" : trades,
        "total_trades" : total_trades,
        "balance" : balance,        
        }
    return render(request, "accounts/user.html", context)
```

I render it as :
this is the table that I want to paginate :)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>No. of Stocks</th>
                    <th>Total Cost of Trade</th>
                    <th>Time of Purchase</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                </tr>
                {% for trade in trades %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{trade.ticker}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.action}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.price_trade_at}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.stocks_bought}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.cost_of_trade}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.time_bought_at}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.balance_of_trader_after_purchase}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please point me in the correct direction, I got no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ajax to serve your table

```
def userPage(request):
    user = request.user
    user_info = user.info
    trades = user_info.trade_set.all()
    total_trades = trades.count()
    balance = round(user_info.balance)
    
    context = {
        "user" : user,
        "user_info" : user_info,
        "total_trades" : total_trades,
        "balance" : balance,        
        }
    return render(request, "accounts/user.html", context)

class TradesListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
    ordering = '-time_bought_at'
    paginate_by = 10
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_info = self.request.user.info
        self.queryset = user_info.trade_set.all()
        return super().get_queryset()
```

In the templates:-
In the template for the trades list view:-

```
<div class="card card-body">
   <table class="table table-sm">
      <tr>
         <th>Stock</th>
         <th>Action</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>No. of Stocks</th>
         <th>Total Cost of Trade</th>
         <th>Time of Purchase</th>
         <th>Balance</th>
      </tr>
      {% for trade in page_obj %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{trade.ticker}}</td>
         <td>{{trade.action}}</td>
         <td>{{trade.price_trade_at}}</td>
         <td>{{trade.stocks_bought}}</td>
         <td>{{trade.cost_of_trade}}</td>
         <td>{{trade.time_bought_at}}</td>
         <td>{{trade.balance_of_trader_after_purchase}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </table>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <button class="page-change-btn" data-url="{% url 'trades-list-view-name' %}?page=1">&laquo; first</button>
            <button class="page-change-btn" data-url="{% url 'trades-list-view-name' %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</button>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <button class="page-change-btn" data-url="{% url 'trades-list-view-name' %}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</button>
            <button class="page-change-btn" data-url="{% url 'trades-list-view-name' %}?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</button>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

In the template for the userPage:-

```
<div class="row" id="trades-table-container" data-url="{% url 'trades-list-view-name' %}">
</div>
```

Now use some javascript to perform ajax and use the url in the data-url of above div and fill the content of response into the div.
Also add javascript on the page-change-btn class in similar fashion

Comment: Hello Abdul, thank you sooo much for the help! Its means a lot that you would give up your time and energy to help me out, it tells me you are a fantastic human and keep doing awesome deeds, dude! :)

Comment: Glad to help. I just noticed I had overlooked something, `data-url="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}` If you make a request to this and other similar urls it would point to the userPage view, you can add `{% url 'trades-list-view-name' %}` this before all of them to prevent such mistakes. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.